# How to stop divs from overlapping as well as scroll along with messages

Tags: html, css, signalr, overlap

I'm creating a SignalR Web Application for messaging. The messages being sent seem to overlap with the footer (textbox, send button), and additionally, not scroll along with the messages being sent.

My CSS is as follows:

```
        body {
            background-color: #2d3436;
        }

        .container {
            background-color: #2d3436;
            padding: 20px;
            color: white;
            max-height: 80%;
        }
        
        .textmessaging {
            background-color: #474f52;
            padding: 20px;
            position:fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #message::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 8px;
        }

        /* Track */
        #message::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        /* Handle */
        #message::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: rgba(67, 74, 139, 0.8);
        }

            #message::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
                background: rgba(67, 74, 139, 0.4);
            }

        #message {
            resize: none;
            outline: none;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            width: 94%;
            color: white;
        }

        #sendmessage {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 50%;
            width: 5%;
            outline: none;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: 1%;
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            border: none;
            border-radius: 6px;
            font-size: x-large;
        }

        #sendmessage:hover {
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }

        #lightmodetoggle {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            border: none;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            font-size: x-large;
            position: fixed;
            outline: none;
        }

        #lightmodetoggle:hover {
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }

        #discussion {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        #messagestyle {
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 6px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div class="container" id="data">
            <ul id="discussion">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="textmessaging">
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message..." rows="3" cols="50"></textarea><button id="sendmessage" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Send!"><i class='far fa-paper-plane'></i></button>
            <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS as follows

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<div><li id="appendedmsg"><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong><br><a id="messagestyle">' + encodedMsg + '<a></li></div>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // var msg = document.getElementById("message");
        // var button = document.getElementById("sendmessage");
        // textBox.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        //    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        //        button.click();
        //    }
        // });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
```

I've done some searching for a while and haven't found anything that suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

hope this can help, I make a little bit changes in your css code

```css
   body {
            background-color: #2d3436;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .container {
            background-color: #2d3436;
            padding: 20px;
            color: white;
            max-height: 80%;
        }
        
        .textmessaging {
            background-color: #474f52;
            padding: 20px;
            position:fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: auto;
            left: 0;
            display: block;
            right: 0;
        }

        #message::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 8px;
        }

        /* Track */
        #message::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        /* Handle */
        #message::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: rgba(67, 74, 139, 0.8);
        }

            #message::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
                background: rgba(67, 74, 139, 0.4);
            }

        #message {
            resize: none;
            outline: none;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            width: calc(100% - 92px);
            color: white;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #sendmessage {
            max-width: 72px;
            margin: 0;
            position: relative;
            height: 49px;
            width: 5%;
            outline: none;
            /* top: 50%; */
            margin-left: 1%;
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            /* transform: translateY(-50%); */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            border: none;
            border-radius: 6px;
            font-size: x-large;
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        #sendmessage:hover {
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }

        #lightmodetoggle {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            border: none;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            font-size: x-large;
            position: fixed;
            outline: none;
        }

        #lightmodetoggle:hover {
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }

        #discussion {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        #messagestyle {
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 6px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }

i.far.fa-paper-plane {}
```

```html
<!-- FontAwesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  

<div id="maincontent">
        <div class="container" id="data">
            <ul id="discussion">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="textmessaging">
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message..." rows="3" cols="50"></textarea><button id="sendmessage" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Send!"><i class='far fa-paper-plane'></i></button>
            <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        </div>
    </div>
```